# how to use si.lpReserved2 in Windows8 VS2013?

Tags: c, delphi, createprocess

I am launching console program from GUI application, right from memory, using [this technique](https://sites.google.com/site/delphibasics/home/delphibasicssnippets/uexecfrommembysteve10120-fixedforwin7x64bytestest). Also I provide some data from GUI to console program via undocumented use of si.lpReserved2 and si.cbReserved2, as [described here](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/undocumented-createprocess).
All that was compiled in VS2010 on WinXP and works well in Windows XP 7 and 8.

When VS2013 comes along, it changed the way of handling those parameters above. If I set them to nil and 0, it works in Windows 8 and others. If try to use them as before, console program is stopped with AppCrash popup message - in Windows8 only, on Windows XP and 7 it still works.

What VS2013 changed in si.lpReserved2, and is any way to continue using it in Windows 8? It's really handy, for very legitimate purposes..

Comment: Nothing here sounds very legitimate. Use the command line arguments. And create processes by calling CreateProcess. What do you expect to happen when you break all the rules?

Comment: I am curious to know what advantages are there of using this technique?

Comment: Disrespecting the official documentation is a great way of making your own software -- and other software on the same computer and other computers -- buggy and slow.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation says:

> **cbReserved2**
>
> Reserved for use by the C Run-time; must be zero.
>
> **lpReserved2**
>
> Reserved for use by the C Run-time; must be NULL.

This could not be any clearer.

If you wish to pass arguments to a new process, do so by way of the command line.